# Return already serialzed type in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I'd like to use WCF to set up a cross-plattform WebService. A problem - actually more a performance issue - is that I'd like to return a Type (let's say Event) and I have this event already in XML. So I'd like to avoid deserializing to Event and then WCF is serializing it back to XML. Any idea how to manage this? What I want to achieve is something like "WCF, this method returns an Event-object but I've already serilized it to XML so take it and don't force me to deserialize it first so you can serialize it again".

Daniel

Comment: Is it a SOAP or a REST service?

Comment: The service will mainly be invoked via SOAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WCF component that does message (de)serialization is the `MessageFormatter`.

Hence, you could provide a custom `IDispatchMessageFormatter`. In the `SeralizeReply()` method (which returns a `Message`) you could use the `Message.CreateMessage()` overload that takes an `XmlReader` and supply an XmlReader that you create from your XML. And that's it. A bit of work to do, though. You need to decide whether it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks, sounds promising. I think I'll give it a try :)

Comment: just a caveat - *in this case* it may be MessageFormatter, since it is SOAP. For *general* WCF, there are other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `Message` class for both service request and response instead of DataContract definition: this should gives you more control on SOAP message structure. If you go down this path however you will need to create a custom proxy ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) for start).

Comment: Thanks, sounds promising. I think I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to do that. Unless your `Event` is large, that extra step *probably* isn't going to hurt you, and at least it is local - and if it *is* large, your main problem is bandwidth, which will be the same either way.

You can expose the data as `XmlElement` in the message, which will avoid this step - but then callers will need to know to recognise it as an `Event` (as all they will see in the mex/wsdl is a chunk-o'-xml).

Ultimately, part of the reason it is doing this is that WCF is an *object* based model, and the serializer can actually be swapped via many tricks - so in terms of the regular WCF model, the fact that you have xml is irrelevant: that might not actually be *anything like* what goes down the wire. It needs the object so it can ask the *actual* serializer to do the job.

Comment: The reason I'd like to avoid this additional step is that the service might by facing up to thousans requests per minute or event more. So avoiding any unnecessary load to the cpu is the main goal. I think bandwidth will be fine.

Comment: Dooh, hit the enter key :) I'd like to have the correct return type in the service description as the current version of the service simply returns xs:any and many people disliked this fact.

Yes, you're right about WCF. But from the current point of view the service will be invoked via SOAP. Invocation via .NET and the optimized protocolls are "a nice to have"-feature. So the fact that I already have my object serialized in XML does really matter ;)